# javascript conditional syntax is not working well

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

- My goal: Get a event only rectangle in Canvas
- I used *if* for filtering location of rectangle but *if* is not working well.
  even I did not click pipe. I could see a log about pipe.

[image]

eventListener

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", e => {
          let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          this.mousePos = {
            x: e.clientX - rect.left,
            y: e.clientY - rect.top
          };
          console.log(this.mousePos.x, this.mousePos.y);
  
if(0 <= this.mousePos.x <300 && 100 <= this.mousePos.y <110) {
  console.log("mouseClicked");
}
```

https://codepen.io/chikichaka/pen/NWRjWyG

Comment: `0 <= this.mousePos.x <300` doesn't check if `x` is between zero and 300.

Comment: JS does not work that way.  You may mean `if(this.mousePos.x  >=0 && this.mousePos.x <=  <300 && this.mousePos.y >= 100 &&  this.mousePos.y <110)`  - x

Comment: In almost all programming languages the expression `2 < 1 < 3` is interpreted as `(2 < 1) < 3`. In some languages like C/C++ and javascript this then results in `(false) < 3` and by type coercion becomes `(0) < 3` and 0 is less than 3 so `2 < 1 < 3` is true even if `2 < 1` is false